# How do you set event handler to hardware buttons in Android?

Tags: android, button, hardware, camera

Seems like a simple question, but I couldn't find an answer to it. I'm trying to write an activity that takes a picture using the camera, and I want to attach an onClickListener to the shutter button on the phone itself, but I don't know how to reference the button.

Answer (score 3):

These come through as keys. Override [onKeyDown](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29) and look for [KEYCODE_CAMERA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#KEYCODE_CAMERA).